# SQL Split a table into buckets of equal size, while preserving groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `table` which has `id` and `group_id` foreign key.

I want to create (N=2) buckets of equal size (approximately), such that all rows with given `group_id` end up in the same bucket.

For example, given:

```
id, group_id
1,1
2,1
3,2
4,NULL
5,1
6,2
```

I get:

```
id, group_id, bucket_id
1,1,1
2,1,1
3,2,2
4,NULL,2
5,1,1
6,2,2
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this that I'm missing?

Comment: What results do you expect if there are 10 rows in `group_id=1` and 2 rows in `group_id=2`

Comment: If the even/oddness of group_id is close to random and close to evenly distributed you can use the modulus of 2 to send every even number to partition 0 and odd to partition 1. Of course this wouldn't work if you had 10 odd numbers and 2 even and wanted two buckets of 6.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the NTILE analytic function

Comment: NTILE() doesn't preserve groupings, they will get randomly assigned. And if I partition, then tiles won't be of equal size?

Comment: there is a partition clause and an order by clause that should preserve the groupings.  if you have unbalanced data to begin with, how do you expect the return to reflect that? for example, what if all the rows are in the same group yet you ask for two buckets?

Comment: In the case of this counter-example, It should return 1 bucket. I think it's better written out as a series of queries with custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

This will do a roughly decent job for two buckets, since the rank will be the same for all like group_ids and you just set the cutoff point midway.

Of course this is brittle, if you have a case with 10 records with {group id: count} like {1: 9, 2: 1} it will still be very skewed.

fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/lbj5sXgo

```
create table some_test_data 
  (
    id integer,
    group_id integer
  );

insert into some_test_data values
  (1,1),
  (2,1),
  (3,3),
  (4,3),
  (5,4),
  (6,5),
  (7,5),
  (8,5),
  (9,6),
  (10,7);

select *,
       case when rank() over ( order by group_id ) < count(1) over ()/2 then 1 
            else 2
        end as bucket
  from some_test_data;
```